# XAMPP Virtual Hosts broken after installing and running Yeoman workflows

Tags: xampp, virtualhost, yeoman

my first question here so please go easy. I'll try be as helpful as I can in providing info.

Running : Mavericks on Mac

Okay, I've been running a XAMPP install for a year or so no troubles, never had an issue setting up my own local **.dev* domains by using the virtual hosts provided by the XAMPP installation.

End of last year I installed an ran a couple *yeoman* web apps for ideas and testing out the framework, until I wanted to use my XAMPP hosts again.

I installed all the apps in individual directories in `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/phpsite1`, `../phpsite2`, `../yo-angular1`, `../yo-angular2` etc...

Let's say for the purpose of this question, `phpsite1` maps to `phpsite1.dev` and so on.

At some point I remember doing a grunt build so it put up a dist folder inside `yo-angular1` folder as you'd expect (I wanted to see what a build looked like). `/yo-angular1/dist/...`

Right, here is the interesting part, When I go to for instance `phpsite1.dev` domain, I get served content from `yo-angular1/dist` folder, instead of it's normal folder (`/phpsite1`).

I've not once changed the vhosts file, or any other settings. I checked `/etc/hosts` and it still maps to localhost so I'm wondering if there is some conflict with the localhost domain, but, In access logs of XAMPP I can see it serving the main file as if it's actually accepting requests. Now it makes me wonder if there is something going on with Grunt itself and yo-angular generator perhaps that might be contributing to the conflicting issues I seem to be having.

That's all I have for now, please if you think you might have any insights into why that might be happening, It would be appreciated.